# Android Compose - After zooming out, part of surface is not drawn

Tags: android, zooming, android-jetpack-compose

Android Studio, Jetpack Compose, virtual device API 24

After zooming out surface, only the part that was visible at the beginning is visible. I want to zoom out and see more that I saw at the beginning.

I also want to be able to drag the surface.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var width = 20
    private var height = 20

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val task = TapaGenerator.build(width, height)

        setContent {
            Android_tapaTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    RenderBoard(width, height, task)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RenderBoard(width: Int, height: Int, task: Task) {
    val minScale = 0.3f
    val maxScale = 3f

    val scale = remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    val translation = remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, offsetChange, rotationChange ->
        scale.value *= zoomChange
        if (scale.value < minScale) {
            scale.value = minScale
        } else if (scale.value > maxScale) {
            scale.value = maxScale
        }
        translation.value += offsetChange
    }

    Surface (
        modifier = Modifier
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale.value,
                scaleY = scale.value,
                translationX = translation.value.x,
                translationY = translation.value.y,
            )
            .transformable(state = state)
    ) {
        Column {
            for (y in 0 until height) {
                Row {
                    for (x in 0 until width) {
                        Square(x = x, y = y, task) // this is composable surface
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]